# FATAL: Failed to install gitlab-runner: Access is denied

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

Please help. No matter what I do, even when I use the "-p" switch which is required it still tells me that access is denied. yes i have full permission for the exe and the folder. Yes cmd is running as administrator

```
C:\Users\username\Desktop\gitlab>gitlab-ci-multi-runner-windows-amd64.exe --version
Version:      9.2.0
Git revision: adfc387
Git branch:   9-2-stable
GO version:   go1.7.5
Built:        Mon, 22 May 2017 16:01:18 +0000
OS/Arch:      windows/amd64
```